# Correct template won't render Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, controller

I'm using sunspot solr for searching on my Ruby on Rails app. I made a new search route, controller and pulling in what I would like to search for both the tool model and inventory model.

However, I can't find a way to render the search controller back to the root_path and/or root_url. I've tried a lot of different combinations and checked out this piece:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Right now the search controller is the following:

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @tools = Tool.search do
      keywords params[:query]
    end.results

    @inventories = Inventory.search do
      keywords params[:query]
    end.results

    format.html { render template: "home" }
  end

end
```

The render template: "home" is not working.  If anyone knows how to redirect this to the root path that would be helpful.

Error message is :

ArgumentError in SearchesController#index
too few arguments.

Answer (score 1):

`format` local variable is nowhere defined in the `index` action which is resulting in the error `ArgumentError in SearchesController#index too few arguments.`

What you need to do is, enclose `format.html` within `respond_to` method call as:

```
respond_to do |format| ## format is defined here
  format.html { render template: "home" }
end
```

Or as you are rendering the view in `html` format, you can directly use

```
render template: "home"  ## Removed format.html {}
```

Also, `template` option is used while rendering an Action's Template from Another Controller i.e.,

If you're running code in an `SearchesController` that resides in `app/controllers` directory, you can render the results of an action `home` to a template in `app/views/welcome` as:

```
render template: "welcome/home"
```

The point is you are either

**using the `template` option in wrong context** i.e., if `home` action is present in `SearchesController` itself then you simply should do

`render action: "home"`

-OR-

`you just forgot to add the view path in front of`home i.e. if `home` action belongs to `WelcomeController` and `home` view resides under `app/views/home` then you should be specifying

`render template: "welcome/home"`

Answer (score 1):

Tools/index worked!

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @tools = Tool.search do
      keywords params[:query]
    end.results

    @inventories = Inventory.search do
      keywords params[:query]
    end.results

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render template: "tools/index"  }
    end 
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use redirect_to like so:

```
redirect_to '/your_route/to_home'
```